# How to hide price in magento2

Tags: magento2

I don't want to use any commercial module for hiding price.and i don't want hide by using templates.
is there any way to hide price from entire site using plug-ins or rewrites?

Comment: Free one: https://marketplace.magento.com/estdevs-hideprice.html

Comment: this extension overriding template.there is a chance for template conflicts with custom themes.

Comment: You can look for anyone depending on your requirements https://magecomp.com/magento-2-hide-price.html
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-call-for-price.html

Comment: I think this extension may solve your problems: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-hide-price/

Comment: Please try our free plugin Magento 2 Hide Price Free. It hides prices for unauthorised Magento customers or replaces it with custom text or button with the popup message. You can configure it on store view level. Let us know how it worked for you! https://mageme.com/magento-2-hide-price-extension-free.html

Comment: https://www.mageants.com/call-for-price-extension-for-magento-2.html , Please check this , i think this is the best way to hide price also have configure options so

Comment: This isnt working! Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox has wrapResult and _toHtml both are protected methods and you cannot write the plugin on protected method. Only preference could work by overriding either wrapResult or _toHtml

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;
use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;


class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{ 
    protected function wrapResult($html)
    {
        return '';  

    }

}
```

Comment: its not working. changes not effect.

Comment: FinalBox isn't cached ?

Comment: Works great. I need to hide regular/final price on related section and how to achieve that?

Comment: well, i just figure out that this only worked for homepage and product detail page, but not with WISH LIST page.
I still have change phtml file

Comment: Can  you please tell me how to get a product id  within this plugin

Answer (score 8):

Create module (eg: **CatalogHidePrice**) with plugin.
**di.xml** should look like:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="cataloghideprice_finalpricebox" type="NAMESPACE\CatalogHidePrice\Plugin\FinalPriceBox"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

In the plugin class `\Plugin\FinalPriceBox\FinalPriceBox` do an around plugin (for me, I have to hide the price based on a product attribute)

```
function aroundToHtml($subject, callable $proceed)
{

    if($subject->getSaleableItem()->getHidePrice()==1){
        return '';
    }else{
        return $proceed();
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't get the value of my attribute. These methods don't work: `getMyAttribute()` and `getData('my_attribute')`. Although the following method works `$_product = $subject->getSaleableItem(); $myAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Lomosh HidePrice is an attribte?

Answer (score 2):

> **Try This code**

**app/code/Vendorename/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="price_hide" type="Vendorename\ModuleName\Plugin\HidePriceBox" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendorename/ModuleName/Plugin**

**HidePriceBox.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\ModuleName\Plugin;

class HidePriceBox
{

    function afterToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, $result)
    {
        // add your logic
        if (condition) {
            return '';
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of would be to just target the price's CSS class and hide it.

No modifying of any themes/template files required and can easily revert the changes by removing the style rule.

Comment: Have you got any example of this?

Comment: @jibingeorge it would vary depending on the theme/template, but just find the css class that is attached to the element you want hidden, then add or modify a style declaration to set it to `display: none`