# how to remove out of stock product price (final_price.phtml - magento 2.4.3p1)

Tags: phtml, magento2.4.3.p1, final-price.phtml

I tried using isSaleable(), getSaleableItem(), is_in_stock, without success.

I'm new to Magento and I don't have much knowledge.

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide the price for the "Out of stock" product correct?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how. 
On the list.phtml page I used '$_product->getIsSalable()', but on final_price.html I can't.

Comment: https://www.integerbyteblog.in/magento/product-price-in-magento-2/

Comment: Please follow this solution : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208417/magento-2-switch-the-price-for-sold-label-after-product-is-out-of-stock#:~:text=Hiding%20price%20for%20out%20of%20stock%20products%20in%20Magento%202,custom%20status%20of%20the%20product

Comment: '$_product->isSaleable()', didn't work as I said previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this in **final_price.phtml** file

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($productId);
```

**and you can add condition like this**

```
if ($productStockObj->getIsInStock())
```

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231941/magento-2-hide-price-for-out-of-stock-products-in-product-page)

Comment: It didn't work, it returns the value empty

Comment: <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($productId);
?>
<?php if ($productStockObj->getIsInStock()) : ?>
    OK
<?php else : ?>
    NOK
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: I tested in magento2.4.6 and it's working for me. are you using a custom theme or module?

Comment: I'm using the client theme (Porto), version 2.4.3p1
BASE\app\design\frontend\Smartwave\theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml

Comment: app/design/frontend/{Theme}/{name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml in this location can you please add code that I added the link in the answer and check if it's working or not?

Comment: I applied it, but it didn't work.

Comment: print the data and check print_r($productStockObj)

Comment: Welcome.. Happy Coding. :)

Comment: Instantiating the object manager in a template this way is a very bad practice.