# Magento2: How to hide product price from the website?

Tags: magento2, price

I want to hide product price from the website.

Comment: you can follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165752/how-to-hide-price-in-magento2

Comment: My problem is solved, Thanks!  @YlgenGuxholli

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide price in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165752/how-to-hide-price-in-magento2)

Answer (score 0):

> File Path: app/code/Solwin/Module1/etc/di.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Solwin\Module1\Block\HidePrice" />
</config>
```

> File Path:  Solwin\Module1\Block\HidePrice.php

```
    <?php
namespace Solwin\Module1\Block;
class HidePrice extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    public function wrapResult($html)
    {
          return '';
    }
}
```