# How to hide product price for entire website in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.2

I have used the below code its not working.

di.xml file:

< config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    < type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        < plugin name="customization_finalpricebox" type="Checkout\Customization\Plugin\FinalPriceBox"/>
    < /type>
< /config>

Plugin file code:
FinalPriceBox.php

```
namespace Checkout\Customization\Plugin;

class FinalPriceBox
{
function aroundToHtml($subject, callable $proceed)
{

    if($subject->getSaleableItem()->getHidePrice()==1){
        return '';
    }else{
        return $proceed();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165752/how-to-hide-price-in-magento2

Comment: Hi, already i tried the above link solution its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try this via custom code or using a third-party extension.

- [How to hide price in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165752/how-to-hide-price-in-magento2)
- https://marketplace.magento.com/estdevs-hideprice.html
- https://mageme.com/magento-hide-price-free.html
- https://www.commerceextensions.com/free-magento-hide-product-price-for-non-registered-users.html

Comment: hello, i'm new to magento, if you know to hide the product price detail using plugin please share the code.

Comment: i have tried based on this link solution.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165752/how-to-hide-price-in-magento2