# How to disable the product price for entire website in magento2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.0

I have used the below code its not working. Please suggest the solution.

if someone know the answer please share the exact code and folder structure. since i'm new to magento.

> di.xml file:

```
    < type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        < plugin name="customization_finalpricebox" type="Checkout\Customization\Plugin\FinalPriceBox"/>
    < /type>
< /config>
```

Plugin file code:

> FinalPriceBox.php

```
namespace Checkout\Customization\Plugin;

class FinalPriceBox
{
function aroundToHtml($subject, callable $proceed)
{

    if($subject->getSaleableItem()->getHidePrice()==1){
        return '';
    }else{
        return $proceed();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165752/how-to-hide-price-in-magento2