# How to override the Catalog Widget PHTML file into custom module?

Tags: magento2, overrides, xml, phtml

I need to override the widget template file `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml` but in xml file the phtml file was not mentioned at any where except on `/etc` folder.

```
<parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
    <label translate="true">Template</label>
    <options>
        <option name="default" value="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml" selected="true">
            <label translate="true">New Products Grid Template</label>
        </option>
    </options>
</parameter>
```

How can I override the `vendor-widget-phtml` file `new_grid.phtml` to my custom module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**this way i get changes of phtml by my custom module**

> *app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" type="MyModule\WidgetOverride\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" />

</config>
```

> *app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Product/Widget/NewWidget.php*

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\WidgetOverride\Block\Product\Widget;

class NewWidget extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget
{
  protected function _construct()
    {
      parent::_construct();
      $this->setTemplate('VendorName_ModuleName::product/widget/content/new_grid.phtml');
    }
}
```

> **now add your phtml file this path**
> *app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml*

frontend shows my changes on product page by override phtml file

[image]
hope this help you :)
Happy coding.

Comment: I have tried this but still the changes I'm doing in the phtml is not showing on frontend.

Comment: Thanks. I will check and update you

Comment: I did try your code but still the update is not showing in frontend.

Comment: yes I have ran all the commands

Comment: I need to show the product price only when we set the custom attribute status as approved from dropdown. I have hide the price by following this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165752/how-to-hide-price-in-magento2 but need the ouput as above mentioned. Please guide

Comment: Sure. one last query, can I use cacheable="false" in di.xml, because the block is not updating only when I clear the cache