# Magento 2: How to add second template file to Catalog Product List widget

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add a second widget template option to the backend of Magento 2 so that when I choose the Catalog Product List widget I will get the choice of two templates.

I have created my second template and called it `grid2.phtml`. When I insert my widget code, I can change `template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml` to `template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid2.phtml` and the template changes fine on the frontend with no problems.

I am, however, having trouble adding "grid 2" as a template option on the template drop-down of creating a Catalog Product List widget page. I have tried adding this as an option in the `widget.xml` file (path below) in the following way

**/vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/etc/widget.xml**

```
<parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
    <label translate="true">Template</label>
    <options>
        <option name="default" value="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" selected="true">
            <label translate="true">Products Grid Template</label>
        </option>
        <option name="grid2" value="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid2.phtml" selected="true">
            <label translate="true">Grid 2</label>
        </option>
    </options>
</parameter>
```

But got an error on the frontend. Is there are a way of adding this second template as an option in the dropdown when creating a new widget?
Thank you!

Comment: check this link hope this help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/324861/how-to-override-the-catalog-widget-phtml-file-into-custom-module/324862#324862

Answer (score 1):

In your `widget.xml` file there are two sections. The first sets out the location of the template files like so:

```
<parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
    <label translate="true">Template</label>
    <options>
        <option name="default" value="Gem_CMS::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" selected="true">
            <label translate="true">Products Grid Template</label>
        </option>
        <option name="account" value="Gem_CMS::product/widget/content/grid_account.phtml" selected="false">
            <label translate="true">Products Grid Account</label>
        </option>
        <option name="homepage" value="Gem_CMS::product/widget/content/grid_home.phtml" selected="false">
            <label translate="true">Products Grid Homepage</label>
        </option>
        <option name="email_marketing" value="Gem_CMS::product/widget/content/email_marketing.phtml" selected="false">
            <label translate="true">Products Grid Email Marketing</label>
        </option>
    </options>
</parameter>
```

The second section defines where the template can be used (the options that display in the dropdown in admin).

```
<containers>
    <container name="content">
        <template name="grid" value="default" />
        <template name="grid-account" value="account" />
        <template name="grid-home" value="homepage" />
        <template name="email-marketing" value="email_marketing" />
    </container>
    <container name="content.top">
        <template name="grid" value="default" />
        <template name="grid-home" value="homepage" />
    </container>
    <container name="content.bottom">
        <template name="grid" value="default" />
        <template name="grid-account" value="account" />
        <template name="grid-home" value="homepage" />
    </container>
</containers>
```

The 'value' in this section needs to match the 'option name' of your template from the first section.